# Using the word "stick"

Tags: grammar

I just came across this sentence and there's something that I feel is wrong in it but I'm not sure why. Could you help?

"Don't stick with your phone all the time..because I want you to enjoy the weekend! but don't forget it at all either, I might be sending you emails."

I can rephrase this in several ways but why I feel that the word "stick" isn't used properly..I know the writer could say "don't be stuck" or "don't stay stucked" but what's wrong with "don't stick"?

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: What it means is that if you have your nose in that phone all weekend she's gonna beat you with a stick!

Comment: @hotlicks..who's she?

Comment: also the stick is used as verb her not a noun..so not that "stick".

Answer (score 1):

"Stick with" literally means "adhere to", but as an idiom means to stay with.  Eg, "Stick with us tonight and you will have fun."  "Stick together" is also a common idiom, as in "We must stick together if we're going to defeat that monster."

The writer could have said "Don't be stuck to your phone ..." or "Don't stay stuck to your phone ...", but there's nothing really wrong with the original.

Comment: So it's fine even if the writer was talking about the future? Appreciate your input. :)

Comment: @MarkUsman - "Stick with ..." would generally be used in when discussing the future.

Comment: Awesome! I think I get it! It's the same as "don't stay with your phone all the time" and we can use this phrase for future as well as for present. 

Your answer cleared things up for me. THANKS AGAIN!!!!

Comment: @HotLicks- is right, it's not wrong, but it's not what I would expect most people to say in that situation.  "Don't stay glued to your phone the whole time." is more common, or "Don't hole up with your phone the whole time." or "Don't just live on your phone the whole time."  "It's tool not your life." ...

Comment: @Jim - Yeah, there are probably a dozen ways it could have been better worded.